# Django Rest Framework permissions not being called

Tags: python, django

I'm currently converting all my views to generics, as I like how cleaner the code gets. I am trying to make my User detail view, like so:

```
# User.views

from Common import view_mixins, view_filters, view_permissions

class UserDetail(view_mixins.IntOrStrLookupMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
   queryset = Profile.objects.all()

   lookup_fields = ('user__pk', 'user__username')
   lookup_url_kwarg = 'userid'

   filter_backends = (view_filters.ResourceVisibilityFilter, )
   permission_classes = (view_permissions.IsOwnerOrReadOnly, )

   serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

   def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       user = self.get_object()
       return Response('whatever')
```

---

```
# Common.view_permissions

SAFE_METHODS = ('GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS')

class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    '''
    Owner of object can GET, PUT, DELETE. Everyone else can GET.
    '''

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print('did you call me?')
        return (
            request.method in SAFE_METHODS
            or
            obj.user == request.user
        )
```

---

```
# Common.view_mixins

class IntOrStrLookupMixin(object):
    """
    Apply to views that can be looked up by slug or pk
    """
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)

        filter = {}

        for field in self.kwargs:
            argument = self.kwargs[field]

            if is_int(argument):
                filter[self.lookup_fields[0]] = argument
            else:
                filter[self.lookup_fields[1]] = argument

        return get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)
```

So my issue is, the permission is never called. I can get the user just fine, but anyone can do PUT or DELETE on which I am trying to prevent.

Comment: While not an answer per se... When I encounter problems like this in DRF I'm grateful for http://www.cdrf.co. Awesome awesome resource that allows you to easily dig into the source code and quickly navigate to see how each bit works together.

Comment: Wow! This is super useful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I encountered this problem. The object level permissions are only called when you use get_object() method to get the object being operated on. Update your update() with this line and you should see the permissions being called. And update your custom get_object() to either call the super method or call the permissions directly

```
class UserDetail(view_mixins.IntOrStrLookupMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    ... blah blah blah
    def update(self, request):
        user = self.get_object()
        return Response('whatever')

class IntOrStrLookupMixin(object):
    def get_object(self):
        ... retrieve the object ...
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

Edit: I filed a bug report about this with the DRF team and they updated the docs. On the permission page in the docs it says "Object level permissions are run by REST framework's generic views when .get_object() is called". I agree that this is a rather subtle thing and is easy to miss.

Edit #2: Looks like the problem is not only in the update() not calling get_object(), but also in the IntOrStrLookupMixin mixin redefining get_object() method. Updated the code to reflect

Comment: Still nothing. :/

Comment: Sorry, I meant for you to update your view class, not your permission class. Updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Yeah still nothing. I can edit a user from a different user and "did you call me?" is never printed in the console.

Comment: Can you update the code with the version you are now trying? I am pretty sure this is the problem.

Comment: Done. Not really much of a difference.

Comment: Ah... I see... stupid me. You are using generics. update() method is for the ViewSets, not for generic views. You need to rename your method to put() and add a method for delete() and whatever other methods you want to support (the generics class you are using supports get, put and delete by default)

Comment: And since you are implementing your own, you might want to just subcass APIView and skip the generics altogether

Comment: No, there should be a way to make this work. It should work according to the documentation. It's a permission class, Django Rest Framework supports them.

Comment: Hmm... looks like I am double wrong anyway. The mixin you are using defines the update(), so it should work.

Comment: What methods does your IntOrStrLookupMixin class defines?

Comment: I've added the mixin to the question.

Comment: Ah, so you are redefining the get_object() method, but do not call the super get_object() and that is where permissions are checked. That is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my mixin, I had to call the `check_object_permissions` method.

```
class IntOrStrLookupMixin(object):
    """
    Apply to views that can be looked up by slug or pk
    """
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)

        filter = {}

        for field in self.kwargs:
            argument = self.kwargs[field]

            if is_int(argument):
                filter[self.lookup_fields[0]] = argument
            else:
                filter[self.lookup_fields[1]] = argument

        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj
```